# Calculating bootstrap confidence intervals on second derivatives of a GAM object

Tags: r, confidence-interval, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I am trying to calculate confidence intervals on the second derivatives of a GAM curve. After estimating the derivatives, the idea is to then use function `boot()` to get confidence intervals, but I am unsure where to apply it along the way, or exactly what statistic(s) to bootstrap.

The following code calculates second derivatives for specific values of `epi.i`

```
library(mgcv)
library(boot)

epi.i<-c(7, 8, 9, 10, 8.01, 6, 7.01, 5.999, 4.003, 12,
 2.01, 7.02, 10.01, 8.2, 5.9, 3.9, 6.999, 4.0001, 3.99, 6.001, 8.001, 5.99,
 7.9, 6.99, 3.98)

Rare25<-c(4.471429, 4.551474, 4.204894, 4.456710, 3.504348, 4.175824, 4.298193,
4.406838, 3.058707, 4.451128, 1.000000, 4.327893, 3.580541, 4.082432, 3.630869,
4.352130, 3.919075, 3.795205, 3.380952, 2.993347, 3.775886, 3.766723, 3.852396,
3.923977, 4.308840)

epismooth<-cbind(Rare25, epi.i)

G2<-gam(Rare25 ~ s(epi.i))
#new data for prediction
newDF<-with(epismooth, data.frame(epi.i=unique(epi.i)))

#prediction for smoothed estimates at each unique epi.i value
#with standard error
B<-predict(G2, newDF, type='response', se.fit=TRUE)

#finite difference approach to derivative following
#example from ?predict.gam
eps<-1e-7                    #finite difference interval
X0<-predict(G2, newDF, type='lpmatrix')


newDFeps_p<-newDF + eps
X1<-predict(G2, newDFeps_p, type='lpmatrix')


# finite difference approximation of first derivative
# the design matrix
Xp<- (X0 - X1) / eps

#second derivative
newDFeps_m <- newDF - eps

X_1<-predict(G2, newDFeps_m, type='lpmatrix')
# design matrix for second derivative
Xpp <- (X1 + X_1 - 2*X0)/eps^2

fd_d2 <- Xpp %*% coef(G2)
cbind(epi.i, fd_d2)
```

Any advice on how to proceed with confidence intervals from here would be greatly appreciated.

The following code is what I have tried, though it's incorrect:

```
bootX0 <- function(formula, data,  indices) {
d <- data[indices,] # allows boot to select sample
X0<-predict(G2, newDF, type='link', se.fit=TRUE)
return(mean(X0))
} 

resultsX0<-boot(data=epismooth, statistic=deriv2,
R=1000, formula=Rare25~s(epi.i))
resultsX0
plot(resultsX0)


bootX_1<- function(formula, data,  indices) {
d <- data[indices,] # allows boot to select sample
X_1<-predict(G2, newDFeps_m, type='link')
return(mean(X_1))
} 

resultsX_1<-boot(data=epismooth, statistic=deriv2,
R=1000, formula=Rare25~s(epi.i))
resultsX_1
plot(resultsX_1)


bootX1<- function(formula, data,  indices) {
d <- data[indices,] # allows boot to select sample
X1<-predict(G2, newDFeps_p, type='link')
return(mean(X1))
} 

resultsX1<-boot(data=epismooth, statistic=deriv2,
R=1000, formula=Rare25~s(epi.i))
resultsX1
plot(resultsX1)



Xpp <- resultsX1$t + resultsX_1$t - 2*resultsX0$t/eps^2

fd_d2 <- Xpp %*% coef(G2)
hist(fd_d2)
```